# Autumn vs Fall - difference in meaning?

Tags: word-difference, nouns

I always thought it's merely a difference between AmE and BrE, then I stumbled upon [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/5sof8o/im_back_talking_about_something_i_havent_done/ddgomlz/) by Gordon Ramsay (about vegetable choice for a small garden):

> Parsnips are amazing through autumn and fall. Not just roasted, but in incredible soups.

I googled the difference and besides BrE and AmE, I only found Canadians treat 'Autumn' as more formal, but with the same meaning.

Is there something I'm missing? Say, 'fall' being 'late autumn' or something?

Comment: As a native brit I also thought "fall" was the American word for autumn.

Comment: There is no useful difference between the two other than the spelling and that one (autumn) sounds more mellifluous than the other. You hear *fall* much more often in AmE, but nobody bats an eye at *autumn*.

Comment: Is it possible he meant 'summer and fall' but made a redundancy department of redundancy error?

Comment: Yes, they are the same. One is not more formal than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I arrived here after googling for the same question. I found the article of slate.com (link bellow) very enlightening, basically they are the same and both were used for a bit of time, but 'autumn' remained in England while 'fall' in US.

http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2012/09/29/why_does_autumn_have_two_names_how_the_third_season_became_both_autumn_and_fall_.html